# What is wrong with this PHP script?

Tags: php, date, mkdir

The following script does not execute:

```
<?php

    $year = date(Y);
    $month = date(M);
    $dirloc = "/images/".$year."/".$month;
    mkdir($dirloc, 0700);

?>
```

Why?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have permissions to create a new directory?

Comment: Do you have any kind of error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot quotes:

```
<?php

$year = date("Y");
$month = date("M");
$dirloc = "/images/".$year."/".$month;
mkdir($dirloc, 0700);

?>
```

Comment: This shouldnt cause the error, because every non-defined constant is treatened as a string.

Comment: @PENDO: Just enable `E_NOTICE` ;) `PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant A - assumed 'A'` (for development even better `E_ALL | E_STRICT`. Thats just everything.)

Answer (score 6):

The path you provide is absolute and you probably don't have the rights to create directories or files there. If you want to create the directory in the current work directory (the one you run the script from), try

```
$dirloc = "images/".$year."/".$month;
```

Also it seems, that you want to create more than one folder. If the parent folder doesn't exists, `mkdir` fails, if you don't allow it to create the parents recursively.

```
mkdir($dirloc, 0700, true);
                  // = recursive
```

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes for the date() function:

```
$year = date("Y");
$month = date("M");
```